# Python: The sequence of inheritance?

Tags: python, sequence

In the example below, I've got 2 parent classes who initialize/declare the same variable. Why does it take the first class and not the second class? This is just for knowledge purposes.

```
class ParentClass:
    one = 'I am the first variable'
    two = 'I am the second variable'
    three = 'I am the thirt variable'


class ParentClass2:
    three = 'I am the third variable'


class ChildClass(ParentClass, ParentClass2):
    two = 'Different Text'
    pass

childObject = ChildClass()
parentObject = ParentClass()

print(parentObject.one)
print(parentObject.two)
print(childObject.one)
print(childObject.two)
print(childObject.three)
```

**Output:**

```
I am the first variable

I am the second variable

I am the first variable

Different Text

I am the thirt variable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because because `ParentClass` comes first in the mro

```
 print(ChildClass.__mro__)
(<class '__main__.ChildClass'>, <class '__main__.ParentClass'>, <class '__main__.ParentClass2'>, <class 'object'>)
```

If you changed the order you would get the output you expect:

```
class ChildClass(ParentClass2,ParentClass):

(<class '__main__.ChildClass'>, <class '__main__.ParentClass2'>, <class '__main__.ParentClass'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Python checks from left to right for the attribute so because you have `ParentClass` first you get the attribute from the `ParentClass` class